# moving html elements from one node to another

Tags: javascript, html

I wanna move an html elements from one node to another but I didn't know how, when I thought about it at first It seems easy but in practice it's a little bit hard I'm still thinking it's silly though.

here is an example:

```
    <div class="container">
    <h1>text</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="con">

    </div>
<button> click ME </button>
```

I wanna move what is inside the `.container` `div`  to the `.co` `div` I have searched a lot on google but I didn't find anything useful, I have searched even here on stackoverflow but I did find a solution.

any help please and thank you in advance

questions I have saw and didn't solve the problem:

[Moving HTML element from one page to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51830314/moving-html-element-from-one-page-to-another)

["Cut and Paste" - moving nodes in the DOM with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324303/cut-and-paste-moving-nodes-in-the-dom-with-javascript)

[How to move all HTML element children to another parent using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910147/how-to-move-all-html-element-children-to-another-parent-using-javascript)

Comment: When shall the moving take effect ? After a `button` click maybe ?

Comment: @ths yes why not

Comment: I didn't see any `button` in your code so I asked.

Comment: I have added one

Comment: I think this answer should be what you looking for [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910147/how-to-move-all-html-element-children-to-another-parent-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution :
**HTML**

```
<div id="parent1" class="container">
  <h1>text</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div id="parent2" class="con">

</div>
```

**JS**

```
let insideContainer = document.getElementById('parent1');
let con = document.getElementById('parent2');

con.append(...insideContainer.children);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a way to remove each element from the `.container` div and then add each of them to the `.con` div. I would do it like this:

```
// get all children of container
const containerChildren = document.querySelector('.container').children;
// turn them into an array and loop through them
Array.from(containerChildren)).forEach((el) => {
    // remove element
    el.remove();
    // select .con and add it to that div
    document.querySelector('.con').append(el);
});
```

You can turn that into a function and then add it to the button like so:

```
function handleClick() {
    const containerChildren = document.querySelector('.container').children;
    Array.from(containerChildren)).forEach((el) => {
        el.remove();
        document.querySelector('.con').append(el);
    });
}
document.querySelector('button').onclick = handleClick;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is : while there is at least *an element* in `div.container` move it to `div.con`. The *an element* is the `JavaScript`'s `HTMLElement` objects `firstChild` attribute, so as long as there is a first child move it to `div.con`.

Here's a demo, it contains a wealth of helpful comments :

```js
/** selecting the main "divs" and the "button" **/
let container = document.querySelector('.container'),
  con = document.querySelector('.con'),
  btn = document.getElementById('move');

/** click handler for the "button" **/
move.addEventListener('click', e => {
  while (el = container.firstChild) con.appendChild(el); /** move the child to the other div and keep their appearnance (placement) as they were in the first "div" **/
});
```

```css
/** some styling to distinguish between the two main eements (divs) **/

.container,
.con {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.container {
  border-color: blue;
}

.con {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- the button is selected in "JavaScript" based on its ID (move) -->
<!-- some styling is used to distinguish between the elements : the ".contaier" has a blue border while the ".con" has a red one. Notice which element has children in it after clicking the "button" -->

<button id="move">Move elements</button>

<div class="container">
  <h1>text</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<div class="con"></div>
```

Answer (score -4):

you can use every class by useing the link of class in your html codes by this syntax :

`<head>
<link href="class.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>`
however if you have not the class file (file.css) , first you have to write your css in the file : class.css and then use that code every where you want !